# How to deny drop permission for a table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, role

Is there a way to deny drop permissions for a specific table from a user or role?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to prevent to drop the table by some user, try this:

```
DENY DELETE ON OBJECT::dbo.table_to_deny TO restricted_user;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173724.aspx

Comment: If this user has a db_owner role, is does not seem to affect the users ability to drop this table.

Comment: If you want to restrict the DBO user right, ask about it. Your question is "Is there a way to deny drop permissions for a specific table from a user or role?". Concerning your comment: prevent DBO user from deleting object in database - bad idea, You just MUST NOT give this user DBO rights. Give him appropriate rights for appropriate objects, but not DBO. DBO is owner of ENTIRE DATABASE.

Comment: I'm talking about db_owner role, not dbo user, those are different things.

Comment: db_owner == dbo user. You should not be giving this privilege to any users. That is all there is to it.

Answer (score 7):

Try using the DDL trigger FOR DROP_TABLE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NO_DROP_TABLE
ON DATABASE
FOR DROP_TABLE
AS
PRINT 'Dropping tables are not allowed'
ROLLBACK
```

Comment: +1. Nice solution to the problem. Of course we prefer not to provide dbo rights to users in the first place :-)

Comment: @RandolphWest true. The number of times I have heard "Just give dbo, so we don't have to worry about permissions". With SQL 2012, you can even fine tune the server role permissions.

Comment: Ok, this prevents drop table for the whole database, not just for one table.

Comment: @jrara, is a database trigger, so yes, in the whole database.